# Why aren't elements on the heap released after the function?

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Someone told me that *'Yes. `node* new_node = new node;` allocates a node on the heap, and `node new_node;` inside a function allocates a node on the stack. If the nodes point to one another, it's still a linked list. Beware though that stack-allocated stuff is automatically released when the function ends. That's why it's more convenient to allocate on the heap.'*

What does it mean? Can someone elaborate?

Comment: This may help understand the difference between stack and heap... https://gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Answer (score 2):

The looong answer.

### Automatic storage duration

"Stack" variables (more properly known as entities with *automatic* storage duration) are destroyed as soon as you leave the scope in which they were declared. (That is, they are "cleaned up" and their memory is released)

```
void my_function() {
  node node1;
  if (1 == 1) {
      node node2;
      node* node3_ptr = new node; // this node is *not* cleaned up automatically
  } // node2 is destructed now
  node node4;
} // node1 and node4 are destructed now
```

In the code above, `node1` and `node4` are declared at different parts of the outermost scope of the function. They will "go away" when the functions ends.

It doesn't matter whether the function runs to the end, returns early, throws an exception - if the function ends, C++ guarantees that they will be destroyed. (The application terminating dead in its tracks is different.)

`node2` is declared inside the `if` block. It will be destroyed when the code leaves the `if` block - even before the function ends.

This guaranteed automatic destruction of these variables at a perfectly predictable time is one of C++ greatest strengths. It's called "deterministic destruction" and is one of the reasons C++ is my preferred language.

### Dynamic storage duration

"Heap" variables (aka entities with "dynamic" storage location) are trickier.

```
void my_leaky_function() {
  node* node5;

  new node;

  node* node6 = new node;
}
```

`node5` is still just a local variable. The fact that it is of type "pointer to node" rather than just "node" doesn't matter. It is a variable with automatic duration, that uses memory. Its size is the size of a pointer (probably 4 or 8 bytes - depends on your platform), not the size of a node. That variable "goes away" and its memory is recovered when the function ends.

`new node;` allocates memory on the "free store" (colloquially called "the heap"). `new` returns a pointer to the allocated memory, but this code ignore the pointer. There are no local variables involved here, and the node is *not* destroyed when the function ends;

`node* node6 = new node;` also allocates enough space for a node object on the free store - but this time the pointer returned by `new` is stored in a local variable called `node6`. NB: `node6` is a local variable (that stores a pointer, not a node) and it has automatic storage duration. The `node6` variable goes away (and the few bytes of memory it uses are released) when the function ends. BUT the node that `node6` was pointing too - the node that is stored on the free store - is *not* destroyed.

When this function ends it has left two nodes on the free store - and because it has thrown away the pointers to each of them, there is no way for anyone to delete them. It has "leaked memory".

### Why use dynamic storage?

C++ promises to clean up your function's automatic storage values whenever you leave their scope. This is normally what you want.

Sometimes a function needs to create a value that outlives the function call - a value that must not be destroyed when the function exits.

Often that value can just be returned to the caller (no `new`, no pointers) and the caller can do what they want with it. Often the value is stored inside some collection like a vector or an array that already have allocated memory for it. But - in your example, you want to create a new node in a linked list or a tree (or something similar) and it would make no sense for the node to be destroyed when the function ends.

### tl;dr;

So

1. if a value must exist after the end of the function that creates it
2. and it is not just being returned to the function's caller
3. and it is not being stored inside the memory of some other container

then the free store is the right place for it.

There is sooooo much more to go into regarding who "owns" the value and is responsible for deleting it - and the use of smart pointers rather than raw pointers - and exception safety - and and and and - but this answer is already bigger than I wanted. So let me just end with this:

While you are learning C++, use pointers. Use the free store. Burn yourself with memory leaks and double deletes. Work out how you would solve those problems. This gives you a great foundation to understand the abstractions you will use later.

Once you understand pointers and dynamic storage - once you understand how you would write your own linked list or binary tree from scratch - STOP USING THEM. In day-to-day coding, unless you are an expert writing code for a container library, never use `new` or `delete` again - ever. Use smart pointers when you absolutely must, but try to avoid even them.

Rely on automatic storage duration whenever you can. Deterministic destruction is your friend. It is what differentiates C++ from C. It is what differentiates C++ from garbage-collected languages. It is why C++ is still one of the kings of programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can still have pointers referencing the same object in previous method calls.